# Why do I get a "Too Large or Too Small" error when calling Texture2D.GetData?

Tags: c#, xna, texture2d, rendertarget

I need to quickly save an image, and I am using Texture2D.GetData and SetData because simply saving and loading the image is way too slow. The image is 1024x1024.

```
RenderTarget2D Image = ChunkContainer.GetImg(x, y);
byte[] imageBuffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
Image.GetData<byte>(imageBuffer);
b.Write(imageBuffer);
```

I get an ArgumentException error:

"The size of the data passed in is too large or too small for this resource."

So I can't save a 1024x1024 image? Is there a better way of doing this? Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forgetting to add the `Bit Depth`, which is typically 4 bytes per pixel (1 byte for each: red, green, blue, alpha). Your array should be: `1024 x 1024 x BitDepth`

Answer (score 1):

What is the [format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.surfaceformat.aspx) of the image? How many bytes per pixel?

Per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197089.aspx), you can see this error when the size of the array you are passing to `GetData` is too small to contain the render target's data. This seems to be the likely culprit here, since you are allocating 1024x1024 *bytes*. Unless you are using the `Alpha8` format, each pixel in the render target is likely going to occupy at *least* two bytes of space. You need to figure out how many bytes are used per-pixel of your render target (by checking the `Format` property, for example). Once you know that, multiply your `1024 * 1024` calculation by that value.

For example, allocate an array of size `1024 * 1024 * 3` if you know your render target uses three bytes per pixel, et cetera.